# mysql dump using php script

Tags: php, mysql, database

I tried the below code to backup my database "db_school".

```
<?php
    shell_exec('mysqldump -u root -h localhost db_school > backup-file.sql');
?>
```

The new file named "backup-file.sql" is created but, the problem is that it is totally empty. Following is my database table:

```
-------------------------------------
id  |  school_name   |  city
-------------------------------------
1   |  cp school     |  New York
2   |  public school |  San Fracisco
-------------------------------------
```

Note: my 'root' user has no password
I know there are many posts on this topic but each suggests the code similar to above

Comment: There may be some error happening and is not captured anywhere, can you try 2>&1 in your command or even echo the output of the command.

Comment: the command runs successfully in shell and even I tried printing the output but it is empty either

Answer (score 1):

Make sure folder having full permission (777 read/write).

because this code create new file name "backup-file.sql" , so folder having permission to create new file.

please give the permission to that folder where this php file executes.

Comment: thanks vishal, i think your answer will make it but I don't know how to give permissions on local machine

Comment: Which operating system you have

Answer (score 0):

try this dear

a set of one or more complete databases

```
<?php
    shell_exec('mysqldump -u root -h localhost --database db_school > backup-file.sql');
?>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but, again the same...an empty file...

could there be problem with my system or xampp?