# backup specific tables/columns using php for each user

Tags: php, mysql, sql

it is my first question here. if I am mistaken sorry for that.

I want, each user of my site, can backup their data from mysql. how can i do it using php?

something like that;

```
    <?php
$userid = 15;
$username = 'memmed';
$filename = $username.$userid.'sql';

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 15;';
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
$text = 'INSERT INTO users (id, name, .. , ......) VALUES('.$row['id'].', ............)';

$handle = fopen('backups/'.$filename,'w+');

fwrite($handle,$text);
fclose($handle); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have given will not do "data backup" It will just do something like save the $text.

If you want to do  mysql backup, try something like

[mysql dump using php script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20000512/mysql-dump-using-php-script)

Comment: I want just for some column backup

Answer (score -1):

just create 2 string as follow

```
$str1='';
$str2='';
    foreach($row as $key=>$value){
                $str1.=$key.',';
                $str2.="'".$value."',";
            }
        }
        $str1=rtrim($str1,',');
        $str2=rtrim($str2,',');

   $text = 'INSERT INTO users ('.$str1.') VALUES('.$str2.')';
```

Comment: This does not answer the question